# How to know when ImageView finishes loading the image?

Tags: java, android, imageview, loading

I have an Activity which loads a custom ImageView ( https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java). Inside onCreate, I use setImageBitmap to display a huge image (4Mb...).

The problem is that this activity takes 4 seconds to show, but there is no blocking method which I could place in a AsyncTask. What I mean is that all my Activity code is executed, but the activity comes only when the image is loaded, and I don't know when its finish.

What I want to do is showing a ProgressDialog while the Activity loads it, and displays it when it's done.

How can I resolve this ? Here is some code.

Hope you'll understand my problem, it's pretty hard to explain. Thanks !

carte.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<loki.test.lokitest.affichage.TouchImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/loading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/bouton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/textBouton"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

CarteActivity.java (The one who takes 4 seconds)

```
public class CarteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Group groupe;
private String android_id;
private ConnexionServeur serveur;
private TouchImageView vue;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("Loki","onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.carte);

    findViewById(R.id.bouton).setOnClickListener(this);

    vue = ((TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.image));
    vue.setImageBitmap(Singleton.getInstance().getImage());

    groupe = Singleton.getInstance().getGroupe();
    android_id = Singleton.getInstance().getAndroid_id();
    serveur = Singleton.getInstance().getServeur();

    if(groupe != null)
            groupe.afficherGroupe(vue);

    }
}
```

**EDIT** : 
The image is loaded with :

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.myImage);
```

But I don't think that this is this code which takes time, it is already done when i use setImageBitmap. I can't figure out what takes so much time, but I wonder if it's a metod I can access.

Comment: Can you post the code that is used to load the image? The code in the function getImage().

Comment: @Oyashiro do post the solution you found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make Layout xml top container (Top RelativeLayout) carry two elements

  1 Progress Bar - With Visibility Set to Visible. Make it large and in the center

  2 Relative Layout - Entire Content Body . Make it invisible first. It will be under progressbar and will be filling entire screen both height and width wise.
- In oncreate setContentView and then starts a AysncTask that loads the imageview in doInBackground.In its postExecute make content body visible and progress bar invisible.
  **Postexecute will get called only after when your loading is complete**

Hope this help and you can translate all this in code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your idea is great and I tried it, but it does not resolve the problem. I've no "blocking code", so the postExecute is executed very quickly, and as the activity is still not displayed, the screen freezes.

Comment: for check, Make onCreate execute setContentView Only. put everything else in doInbackground. and ui changes in onPostExecute. and in the last make progress invisible and content visible. And if this doesn't work . Only God Know whats exactly going on. Mine Hands are up :)

Comment: Ok so I tried this, but it still not work as I want. I tried the same code on another phone, and there is no delay...